# Table not found in Production - Laravel

Tags: laravel-8

I have what people say "it works on my computer" issue.
On my Trait, I have the following code:

```
use App\Models\Lessons;
...
$lessons = Lessons::find($lesson);
```

But when I fire this up in production, it gives error message `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table db.Lessons doesn't exist (SQL: select * from` Lessons`where`Lessons`.`id `= 5 limit 1) ...`.

I check my model and I can find `protected $table = 'Lessons';`.  (This was the #1 SO answer given based on the related question)
I also checked the DB and I can see the `lessons` table.

BTW, this works in local.

I have tried deleting the DB, and rerunning artisan/seeder/etc (This a new install so no problem dropping) but still getting the same issue. Any opinions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Case sensitive? in your text you talk about 'lessons' and 'Lessons'?

Comment: Did you try it with a other table? maybe your database connection or database is wrong

Comment: @Elias Yes other tables are working without issue. I will try to change it to lower case. btw. CamelCase Lessons is currently working on local though.

Comment: so it was a case sensitive issue. Though I cant seem to figure out why it was working in the local though. Thank you.